# PhoneGap Android with SSL fails after signed

Tags: android, ssl, cordova, keystore, signed

I am developing an app that works fine in debug mode running from eclipse. But when it is exported from eclipse unsigned and then signed on our server with our keystore, it can no longer access Internet. The app uses only SSL. We have a Godaddy ssl cert on the server.

The app uses Phonegap with following permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
```

The app works fine in iOS installed from App Store, using the same javascript code to access the services.

I can't find much information about what can be wrong here. I do know that I have had issues before with Godaddy ssl certs on the java platform. But since it works in eclipse debug mode, I can't see that as the reason.

Any ideas anyone?

*Update:*
**Problem/Solution**
The Eclipse signed debug apk was able to use a GoDaddy SSL certificate without the intermediate certificate installed on the server.

Comment: why don't you sign the code directly in Eclipse?

Comment: Because we have a keystore on a server (backup reasons) that we are using.

Comment: how about trying to export a signed app in Eclipse, then upload it as a dummy app (non-published) to Google Play and try to install it? if the problem is not there, maybe you're missing something in your `config.xml` file - like a whitelisted domain or so?

Comment: OK thanks, I will try to export and sign in Eclipse. 
I have <access origin=".*"/> set in config.xml.

Comment: this could not be the issue, but maybe adding `subdomains="true"` (i.e. `<access origin=".*" subdomains="true" />`) could help a bit, too?

Comment: Ok, so I exported and signed directly from eclipse, and added subdomains="true" in the conifg.xml file. It is still not working. I changed so that the app is using HTTP instead of HTTPS and then it works.

Comment: @xoda I having the same problem also. I tried accessing a data from a server using `https` and for some reason it does not work anymore when an apk is signed. Do you ask for ssl certificate from the data provider/server and use that certificate to signed the apk?